# How can i do a "Crouch" with only a Character Controller with no rigidbody?

Tags: unity, c#, first-person-shooter

I was following Bracky's fps tutorial but he didn't add crouching as an option. I took a stab at it but came up empty handed. Here is my script for player movement.

public class PlayerMovment : MonoBehaviour
{
public CharacterController controller;

```
public float speed = 12f;
public float gravity = -9.81f;
public float jumpHeight = 3f;

public Transform groundCheck;
public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
public LayerMask groundMask;

Vector3 velocity;
bool isGrounded;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

    if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
    {
        velocity.y = -2f;
    }

    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
    }

    velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

And also have a separate script for mouselook, here that is aswell.

public class Mouselook : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;

public Transform playerBody;

float xRotation = 0f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    xRotation -= mouseY;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
    playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
}
```

}

How would I go about adding one without adding a rigidbody or changing my script fully to follow other tutorials? Thank you!

Comment: You tagged this question as "C++" and wrote "C++" in the title, but the code you posted rather appears to be in C# than C++. Are you sure you mean C++ and not C#? (While it is possible to use C++ in Unity through external DLL plugins, that's a very unusual approach to Unity development)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a character crouch?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/169627/how-can-i-make-a-character-crouch)

Comment: I've linked this question to some existing answers we have on the topic. If you're unable to make those answers work for your case, edit your question to show where you ran into trouble (and fix the language tagging), and we can re-open it for answers specific to that issue.